# Anguilla XML / Json Libraries

Tags: gui-extensions, xml

Just wondering if there's already some sort of XML and Json library to process item xml when working with GUI extensions.. before I write my own.

Say i'd like to get an object's data as xml, convert it to json, send it somewhere for manipulation, then when it comes back convert back to Tridion xml and save etc.

If it already exists that would be lovely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much options. If you are using tcm items then i'd say

`Object.serialize($model.getItem("tcm:0-1-1").getXmlDocument())` -> send for manipulation -> `$tcm.getItemFromXml(Object.deserialize(result).xml)`

But I can assume, you won't be able to serialize XML documents due to its size.